# When do I need to create a Docker image in my Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins, pipeline

I was taking a look at the jenkins in file in our organization and noticed that we are building a docker image on every commit.
In my opinion, it doesn't make sense to build a Docker image if the image is not pushed to a registry ( and destroyed when the Jenkins job is over).

The only times we push the Docker image to the registry is for the following branches :
1-Develop
2-Master
3-Support

Question 1: Am I correct not to want to create a Docker image for every commit?
Question 2: Can anyone share with me an example of a Jenkins pipeline for a frontend application?

Thank you

I took a course on Docker to understand better the concept of image creation.

Answer (score 0):

Building the Docker image for every commit makes sense if you want to ensure that the Docker image gets built properly (to make sure there were no changes in the commit that stops the image from building / fails the build). Without this check, it is possible to make some sort of mistake (such as adding incorrect commands to the Dockerfile), then merge the commit to master, at which point the build will fail since the Docker image cannot get built. Since you ideally want to catch errors before they are merged into master, you want to build each commit.

As for your second question, it is too broad. The pipeline would change depending on what frontend framework you were using, what sort of tests you wanted to run (unit tests/selenium tests, etc...).

Comment: Thank you for for you answer M B. However please note that the dockerfile are never touched in such commit. It is only the content of the source code that is changing which will not actually affect the creation of the docker image. I think the unit tests are the one that will catch an error if the commit contains error but it is not the job of the docker image creation to do so.

Comment: If that is the case and the image is not being used at all then yes, there is no reason to have the image built.